# Remove JS from Print CSS

Tags: php, javascript, css, printing

So I've working on a website and i'm just doing the finishing touches, I've used a lot of javascript on this and it keeps showing within the print version of the site... even if I comment it out, I was just wondering if anyone was aware of a way of removing javascript from the print version of the site easily, and if it's any help, the site is written in PHP.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
The javascript itself is not running, its directly showing the code itself, rather than running it, and if possible I would like to remove all the javascript elements entirely.

Comment: What do you mean, the JavaScript is "showing"? JavaScript included correctly on the page is not shown in the print output.

Comment: Editted to make the question more clear.

Comment: Did you add type attribute to script tag?

Comment: I think what the OP is trying to say is, he has a print css that formats a page for PRINTING! however some javascript code is DIRECTLY in the html, and the JAVASCRIPT CODE is being displayed when he prints the page. So how can he HIDE the JAVASCRIPT CODE when the page is PRINTED!

Comment: Exactly... and as for posting the code, I haven't written any yet, I'm trying to get some advice on writing it.

Comment: @AaronLee Apologies, +1 Good question! You will need to write your own print function to filter out all JS, will not be nice!!

Comment: So you want to print source code, and not the page itself?

Comment: You can define print areas in your code which will exclude the javascript or otherwise include javascript code in non printable div areas.

Comment: *"The javascript itself is not running, its directly showing the code itself, rather than running it, and if possible I would like to remove all the javascript elements entirely."* That doesn't make any sense. If the code is in `script` elements, it **will not show in the printout**. You'll need to create an example of what you're talking about and post it in the question for the question to make sense.

Comment: Maybe you have some kind of weird rule in your print css. What happens if you add a CSS rule like `script{display:none !important}`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know what you mean, but everything within the script elements is being pasted as code on the print page. If you go on this site www.a3mediauk.co.uk and try to print the page you'll see exactly what I mean

Comment: @AaronLee: Links are an okay *adjunct*, but don't expect people to follow them. Show code/markup **in the question itself**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: As previously stated above... their is no code. I am trying to get that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this PHP code:

```
$str = file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com");
$pattern = '#\<script.*?\>(.*?)\<\/script\>#si'; 
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
die($str);
```

It removes all script tags from inside. Now you can print it...